# Why the current of double layer charging is independent of potential?

Tags: electrochemistry, cyclic-voltammetry

*i-V* curve of double layer charging has a rectangular shape. Why when increasing or decreasing the voltage, the current remains constant?

Or I can ask, how the double layer structure is changing by varying the applied voltage?

Answer (score 1):

Wow thats a really old question but here is the answer: for electrochemical systems, C is a constant and I=C*(dV/dt) and dV/dt is the scan rate which scales the potential linearly (so is also constant).